# Image enhancement before CNN helpful?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a Deep learning model ( transfer learning based in keras) to do regression problem on medical images. Does it help or have any logical idea or doing some image enhancements like strengthening the edges or doing histogram equalization before feeding the inputs to the CNN?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to train model accurately by using something you told.

For training CNN model with data, they almost use image augmentation in pre-processing phase.

There are list usually used in augmentation.

- color noise
- transform
- rotate
- whitening
- affine
- crop
- flip
- etc...

You can refer to [here](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)